# Is there any script to get logged in user info via email

Tags: powershell

Hi guys I am wondering if there is any script that will notify with email about logged in user information like username, computer name, client ip, client name, date and time etc.

Here is the script i get from technet but it displays computer name as local host, can it output a logged file and email as attachment?

```
Param(
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost'
)

Begin {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
}

Process {
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        try {
            quser /server:$Computer 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
                $CurrentLine = $_.Trim() -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s'
                $HashProps = @{
                    UserName = $CurrentLine[0]
                    ComputerName = $Computer
                }

                # If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
                if ($CurrentLine[2] -eq 'Disc') {
                    $HashProps.SessionName = $null
                    $HashProps.Id = $CurrentLine[1]
                    $HashProps.State = $CurrentLine[2]
                    $HashProps.IdleTime = $CurrentLine[3]
                    $HashProps.LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..6] -join ' '
                    $HashProps.LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
                } else {
                    $HashProps.SessionName = $CurrentLine[1]
                    $HashProps.Id = $CurrentLine[2]
                    $HashProps.State = $CurrentLine[3]
                    $HashProps.IdleTime = $CurrentLine[4]
                    $HashProps.LogonTime = $CurrentLine[5..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
                }

                New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HashProps |
                Select-Object -Property UserName,ComputerName,SessionName,Id,State,IdleTime,LogonTime,Error
            }
        } catch {
            New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                ComputerName = $Computer
                Error = $_.Exception.Message
            } | Select-Object -Property UserName,ComputerName,SessionName,Id,State,IdleTime,LogonTime,Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you written anything yet ? You can edit your question and add some code in it, so we can help you.

Comment: How do you use the script ? I believe it's meant to be saved in a `.ps1` file and called with a `-ComputerName 'hostname'` parameter, allowing you to choose the targeted computer. Here, `'localhost'` is the default value for this parameter. To send an email, check the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx - PS 3.0 required)

Comment: Planning to schedule it with task schedular > at logged in event, can it generate client name ? and computer name?

Comment: I guess so, just try it : ) program = `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, arguments = `-File "C:\path\to\script.ps1"`

Comment: Finnaly after lot of trail and error i got poweshell script that send email.

$From = "fromaddress@domain.com"
$To = "toaddress@domain.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "username@gmail.com"
$Password = "gmailpassword"
$subject = "Email Subject"
$body = "Insert body text here"

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);

$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body);


Can i get the output of the above command as email body?

Comment: Sure, in your Process block, try `$body = foreach($Computer in $ComputerName) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

I guess script usage should be:

- save it in a `.ps1` file
- call it with a `-ComputerName 'hostname'` parameter, allowing you to choose the targeted computer

Here, 'localhost' is the default value for this parameter.

To send an email, check the [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet (PS 3.0 required).

If you need to run a script as a scheduled task, set the `Action` fields like this:

program = `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

arguments = `-File "C:\path\to\script.ps1"`